# Angularjs timepicker dropdown

Tags: angularjs, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I tried to create to dropdown for timepicker using `uib-dropdown` in angularjs but it does not work. Also, in my input text box, I want to display `09:00:00` instead of `Wed Mar 01 2017 09:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`. Any help please?

[plunker here](http://embed.plnkr.co/BGI7MKxmRaFWfEykC75B/)

Thanks

Comment: What part of `uib-dropdown` isn't working?

Comment: hi, if you look at the plunker, the dropdown does not work for some reason : http://embed.plnkr.co/BGI7MKxmRaFWfEykC75B/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the second part of your question. Use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for date formatting.

Add this line of code:

```
$scope.mytime = $filter('date')(new Date("2017-03-01 09:00:00"), 'mediumTime');
```

I also added a $watch for the timePicker's model. Find the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/aOyj5U?p=infov) here.

Comment: it returns Invalid Date on the input

Comment: I have assigned a random date to the `$scope.timePicker` in my plunk, now it no longer says Invalid Date on the input.